# message: 'Unknown authentication strategy "admin-login"' jest testing using supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I am trying to test a Nodejs application that uses express and passport.js.

So in my main `app.js` file I am requiring passportConfig file like this:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const passportConfig = require('./routes/passport.js');
// Configure global passport object
passportConfig(passport);
```

This is what my custom passport.js file looks like:

```
// load all the things we need
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const sha = require('sha256');
const sql = require('mssql');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const connection = require('../middleware/database');

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = async function (passport) {
  const pool = await connection;
  .......
  .......
```

As you can see I am obtaining the passport object passed into this module from `app.js` and loading various strategies to it. Within this function I have:

```
passport.use('admin-login', new LocalStrategy(
    {
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
      usernameField: 'username',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true, // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    ((req, name, password, done) => { // callback with name and password from our form
      async function verifyAdminAuth() {
```

Everything is working node and express wise. Express makes the global passport object and all of the strategies are available everywhere.

Now, my login route file `login.js` for admin login looks like this:

```
const passport = require('passport');
router.post('/login/admin', bouncer.block, passport.authenticate('admin-login', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/failure',
}), (req, res) => {
});
```

As you can see above, I am loading passport.js straight from the node_modules library so it should not have the custom strategies I implemented. However, with the magic of express,  since express caches the library it loads with all of the custom strategies that I have added event though was in the `app.js` file.

I can use my browser to send a post request with username and password params to `/admin/login` and everything works fine. But when doing the same thing from jest using supertest, it throws an error saying :

> POST /login/admin 500 28.396 ms - 7976   console.log
>
> ```
> {                                                                                                                                                                                      
>   status: 500,
>   message: 'Unknown authentication strategy "admin-login"',
> ```

This is what my test file looks like:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const { app } = require('../app');

/* eslint-env jest */
// Info on Mocking: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html

describe('POST /postNewBook', () => {
  test('should return status 200 ', async () => {
    const agent = request.agent(app);

    // This route requires an authenticated user. So lets create an authenticated agent 
   // we will just piggyback off of it and make further requests.

    const res = await agent.post('/login/admin').send({ username: 'Admin', password: 'MyAdminPassword' });

    // Before moving on lets check if agent is authenticated
    console.log(res.body);
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  });
```

I am very new to both `jest` and `supertest`. My understanding was that supertest will load the Nodejs server exactly like just running the node server yourself using the command line. I have been able to do other simple get and post route testing with it with success. But there seems to something that I am missing when it comes to testing authenticated routes. Why does `supertest` not recognize that "admin-login" authentication strategy has been added already. Yes it is not in the same file as `login.js` but if it is running everything the same why is it failing here?

Comment: I would think that jest mocked passport (and its calls) so your call to desrcibe what `admin-login` is was not really parsed by it

Answer (score 0):

you should know ,`passport` strategy, are not automatically available in the context of your test so , you need to export the `passport` from your `passport.js` file and require it in your test

for example

```
const request = require('supertest');
const { app } = require('../app');
const passport = require('../routes/passport'); // import the passport object

describe('TEST`', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    passport(passport);
  });

  test('login test (should return status 200)', async () => {
    const agent = request.agent(app);
    const res = await agent.post('/login/admin').send({ username: 'admin', password: 'admin' });
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  });
});
```

it's should work